# Working with PHP to control Nagios

Tags: php

To monitor an host and some services with Nagios, we have to edit the text file with something like:

```
define host{
use <template>
host_name <name>
alias <alias>
address <IP> }

define service{
use <template>
host_name <name>
service_description <desc>
check_command <command> }
```

I have an interface where I can do something like that with PHP language. I have 2 functions addServiceNagios($hostname, $service, $command) and addHostNagios($hostname, $hostIP) where the information is placed in the file. Now I have a big problem:

The information is always placed no matter what.. If the host already exists, or if the services are already assigned to hosts. What's the best approach to check if the host is already defined? And if the services are associated? And if I want to erase the services that are associated to the host? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use NagiosQL PHP based configuration editor?

Answer (score 0):

I would build a parser that parses the syntax from the file so is able to display the same data in a more accessible data-structure like an array.

Depending on how large the files are, the array could store additional information like offsets etc.. However it's easier next to the parser to write a dumper that can dump this array structure back to file. So each time the whole file is rewritten but with the actual data.

You can then perform add and remove actions on the array structure easily while taking care that reading and writing the file works.

So you've seperated the problems from each other.